Parallels between Michael Malone's novel "Handling Sin" and Cervantes' novel "Don Quixote"
Handling Sin is a hilarious novel by Michael Malone, where the protagonist makes an epic journey across the American South, chasing his father, who has discharged himself from the hospital and taken off for parts unknown. In an interview, in January magazine (2002), Michael Malone says

Handling Sin is a rewriting of Don Quixote, a comic picaresque.

Aside from the fact that they are both comic picaresque novels, are there more parallels between these two books? What are they?

Handling Sin by Michael Malone is a very amusing book, detailing the adventures of its hero, Raleigh Hayes, as he blunders around the southern USA trying to carry out a list of tasks assigned to him by his father. This indeed bears a superficial similarity to the adventures of Don Quijote, where the titular knight also travels around his country, falling into various comic situations along the way. However, I find the claim that Handling Sin is “a rewriting” (in Malone’s words) of Don Quijote to be something of an exaggeration. The reason for the trips, the types of adventures that the respective heros encounter, and their responses to them are very different between the two works.
To begin with the characters, both Raleigh and Quijote  are comfortably off members of the middle class - Quijote is a hidalgo, the lowest order of Spanish nobility, while Raleigh is an insurance agent. This gives both of them the freedom to go on their quests, although Raleigh frequently calls to his office to check that his secretary is coping with running the business in his absence. Their family situations are very different however. Quijote lives with his niece and a housekeeper (“a woman on the wrong side of forty”), while Raleigh is a family man with a wife and two teenage daughters. A major subtext of Handling Sin is Raleigh falling back in love with his wife again, a theme which is, naturally, completely absent from Don Quijote.
A major contrast between the two works is the characters’ motives for embarking on their quests. Raleigh goes under duress, his father giving him a list of specific tasks that he has to complete. Quijote goes insane from reading too many books, and sets off in search of adventure as a knight errant, to try and restore the golden age of chivalry. Raleigh, however, remains obstinately sane and grounded in reality. On encountering a windmill the Don might fantasise it as being a giant, whereas Raleigh would no doubt just see it for what it was. Indeed when Raleigh is performing his first task (stealing the bust from the public library) he muses how “he had stopped reading books… Somewhere along the line he’d grown too busy, too old, too serious for stories”.  Undoing this “serious” aspect in his nature and recovering his joy in life is one of the main reasons for his father to have come up with his scheme. Thus Quijote spontaneously sets off, full of joy and looking for random adventures, whereas Raleigh goes reluctantly with a specific to-do list imposed on him by someone else.
The parallels between the two narratives are probably strongest when the two characters begin their quests, for which Malone explicitly borrows Cervantes’ phrasing by also calling it “The First Sally” At this stage both the men are working alone, having not yet acquired their “squires”, and make the first step on their journeys. Quijote is knighted, and then after being defeated in battle with a muleteer is brought back home to be cared for in his house. In his first sally, Raleigh gets started on crossing off items from his list (arranging the purchase of the cabin on Knoll Pond and stealing the bust of Peewee Jimson from the library), and then like the Don returns home exhausted.
When they recuperate, they both set off on the next phase of their adventures, and each acquire a companion/assistant. Quijote hires the services of a poor farmer named Sancho Panza, while Raleigh, somewhat against his will, is accompanied by his neighbor Mingo Sheffield. Both companions share a similar role of blindly trusting the wisdom of their “master” (Raleigh is not really Mingo’s master, but Mingo is definitely subservient to him), and both chatter incessantly. Both also have characteristic mannerisms in speech: Sancho constantly spouts proverbs, while Mingo interprets everything in terms of movies he has seen (“Mingo kept pausing to ooh and gawk and dawdle and touch and say it all looked just like Gone With the Wind” and so forth).
The actual adventures the characters have are actually not very similar. Raleigh is specifically seeking his half-brother Gates and a jazz musician named Jubal Rogers, whereas Quijote’s trajectory is less directed, leading him into a series of random encounters. One commonality is that they are both partially responsible for the release of a convict: Quijote frees the criminal Ginés de Pasamonte when he encounters a group of convicts being taken to the galleys, while Raleigh and his associates assist Simon “the Weeper” Berg to escape from prison. The similarities stop there though. Ginés steals Sancho’s donkey, and later reappears in Part II of Don Quijote in the guise of a puppeteer to humiliate Quijote, while the Weeper is a more sympathetic, and indeed useful figure, who helps in several of Gates’ schemes.
The ending of Part I of Don Quijote also has some parallels with the final chapters of Handling Sin. In both cases the title characters have accumulated an entourage of characters, and they stay in an inn, before the final acts of the two novels. Again Malone echoes the titling used by Cervantes, with a chapter entitled “The Very Extraordinary Adventures Which Ensued at the Inn” resembling “In which a further account is given of the singular events at the inn”. The conclusions of the two novels are very different however. In one, Quijote is tricked by his companions, and brought back to his home caged in a cart, while in Handling Sin, Raleigh’s father dies having seen his son complete the list of tasks, and Raleigh takes the body back to his hometown to be buried. Raleigh is in a sense reborn and redeemed by his adventures, and recovers the love of his wife and family, and his sense of fun. Quijote, however, returns home under duress, as mad as when he left (his eventual return to sanity, and subsequent death, occurs at the end of less well-known Part II of the story, published 10 years after Part I).
So in broad strokes, there are indeed some similarities between the two works. Depending on how you define “rewriting”, this may be sufficient to justify Malone’s comment. For me, however,  there is a huge difference between Quijote and Raleigh. Quijote is a consummate improvisor - anything that he sees is seamlessly woven into his narrative. A barber’s bowl becomes the prized “helmet of Mambrino”, wineskins hung in his bedroom become giants, a humble inn becomes a stately castle. In contrast, Raleigh simply cannot improvise. As he himself remarks when his father asks him to play the trumpet at a jazz concert, he has to have the notes written down for him:

"I'm, I'm... not like you people. I can't play by ear. I have to
have things written down."


The other answer (by Clara Diaz Sanchez) details several similarities between Handling Sin and Don Quixote in certain plot elements and in their characters. There is an important similarity between these novels that Clara missed, and which may have even been the original inspiration that led Michael Malone to write his book.
Don Quixote doesn’t understand what is going on.
His view of the world has been distorted by the books on chivalry and knights errant which he has been reading, and he misinterprets things: he takes windmills for giants, inns for castles, and a band of innocent travelers for an company of evil knights. As he travels through Spain with his faithful squire Sancho Panza, his delusions lead to comical misadventures.
The hero of Handling Sin, Raleigh Hayes, also doesn’t understand what is going on. Specifically, he doesn’t understand people, especially people who act irrationally (which encompasses just about everybody). It’s harder to pinpoint the exact nature of his delusions, but he seems to divide the world into good and bad people: he believes that bad people are capable of any villainy1, while he believes that good people behave according to the precepts that are taught in Sunday school. As he travels the South with his loyal neighbor Mingo Sheffield, his delusions lead to comical misadventures, although
one difference between these books is that most of the comical misadventures in Don Quixote stem from Quixote’s deluded view of the world, while a considerably smaller percentage in Handling Sin stem from Raleigh’s deluded view or the world.
I now give some evidence for the above assertions.
The narrator refers to this inability to understand the world several times in the text.

Raleigh’s inability to understand unreason made him feel very vulnerable; he was incapable of predicting the path of the erratic, and what he couldn’t predict, he couldn’t cope with.

And later:

All his life, he’d clung to reason like a parachute. What didn’t make sense couldn’t be true.

And yet again, at the point when he is starting to realize that his view of the world is flawed:

Raleigh then sat for a while to think about Right and Wrong. They had never given him any trouble before, but over the past week, they had undeniably begun, in Flonnie Roger’s phrase, to act up. Raleigh suddenly, and very oddly for so literal a man, started to think of these two abstractions as circus jugglers who were tossing rings back and forth so fast that he couldn’t tell whose were whose. Here he was, trying to stand by Right, and somehow ending up on Wrong’s side over and over again.

Nearly three quarters of the way through the book, the narrator explains why Raleigh can’t understand people:

All his life, Raleigh congratulated himself that it was not in his character to open mail not addressed to him, to open doors without knocking, to pry when it was none of his business. When his Hayes relatives began chortling together through long evenings of garbled gossip about each other or anecdotes about whatever they had managed to remember or make up about the Family Past  ("Tell the one about when Papa went up with the barnstormer and the wing fell off. Tell the one about Aunt Mab and that jibber-jabber bigamist from Chicago"), Raleigh picked up an erector set or a stereo kit or a book. He, frankly, wasn't interested.
And therefore, his grandparents, his uncles and aunts, even to a degree his parents (all the adults that had peopled the child’s world) stayed, in some sense, the flat distant figures (however fleshy and noisy) they had seemed to the child: a composite picture of a few poses, a few phrases, a few stories, without precedence or consequence, or connections.

And here are a few examples of his deluded views of people:
First, Raleigh’s reaction when he discovers his neighbors, Mingo and Vera (whom he considers good people) skinny-dipping at night in the community pool:

Unless his weak eyes deceived him, the paddling Vera was…yes, she was definitely bare-breasted. Hayes trod water backward. “What are y’all doing here?”
“Ush?” Spluttered Vera. “Ud boud oo?”
All three circled in a dog paddle, Mingo careful to block Vera from Raleigh’s view.
“Mingo, y’all are breaking the rules. You know the pool’s closed.”
“Tough titties,” incredibly replied the man Hayes had befriended since boyhood.

(Vera cannot speak well because her mouth has been wired shut to help her lose weight. Decoded, her words are “Us? What about you?”)
And here is Raleigh’s brother Gates talking to him:

“Right, yeah, great. I was in prison, you know, not so far from here. … What a pisser! You came to see me, first Saturday of every month, never missed. Told me I deserved to be there and then never missed a visit. Right, Raleigh? Brought me some magazines and gave me a lecture. Every first Saturday. You always did the right thing. Good old Raleigh. Man oh man, what a world.”

Another example: when Raleigh and Mingo are stranded after running out of gas, they get a ride from a bunch of hippies. (I think they’re hippies, Raleigh and Mingo refer to them as Hell’s Angels, which is clearly incorrect.) Raleigh is scared of them and insults them, which leads to a fight, and Raleigh and Mingo getting kicked out of the van with a black eye apiece:

Our hero, in whom righteous indignation had always been a stronger emotion than self-preservation, exploded, “I don’t know what you filthy perverts think you’re up—“

If he hadn’t insulted them, I presume the hippies would have dropped thrm off at the first gas station. As it is, the hippies at least have the decency to throw their possessions out of the van after them, although not before removing the cash from their wallets.2
And here you see Raleigh classify a tenth-century saint as a bad guy:

And for the occasion [St. Patrick’s Day], Sister Joe, announcing she was glad to say her parents came from Galway, read a tenth-century prayer by St. Brigid of Kildare, which ended, shockingly, as far as Raleigh was concerned:
I would like a Great Lake of beer
For the King of Kings.
I would like to be watching Heaven’s family
Drinking it through all Eternity.
Apparently, St. Brigid had been one of those ne’er-do-well good-time Charlies, whose company the savior preferred to that of decent men and women.

Is Raleigh cured by the end? At least partially. Shortly before their travels are over, he thinks:

Here he was with four men, not one of whom he’d originally wanted to bring along, all of whom had caused him endless trouble and worry; none of whom bore the vaguest resemblance to his own “type of person.” And now, when he could already see the lights of the city where all their travels together would end, and their separate lives begin, all he could think was that he was going to miss them.

Raleigh also realizes that his insistence on doing the right thing has made him insufferable. Here he is on an airplane after decoding a secret message, the secret key of which was based on the book of Job in the Bible:

By the time the No Smoking light went off, Raleigh had extracted the message from Job. In so doing, he parenthetically read the miserable man’s story, struck by echos of his own indignation, his own refusals to deny his righteousness, his own realization that his righteousness was, like this tiny aluminum container now shooting through the measureless night, neither here nor there.

He has also overcome his repulsion for not doing the right thing:
Towards the beginning of the book, Raleigh manages to blackmail Pierce Jimson without realizing it. The Hayes family and the Jimson family have been feuding for one or two generations, and Raleigh’s father has asked Raleigh to buy a secluded cabin from Pierce. Raleigh asks Pierce to sell him the cabin after coming from a breakfast attended by several local businessman, at which it was mentioned that Lizzie Joyner was having an affair. Raleigh keeps bringing up Lizzie Joyner’s affair, partially because he feels socially awkward talking to a family enemy. What Raleigh doesn't realize is that Pierce is the person Lizzie is having an affair with. However, Pierce is convinced that Raleigh knows about it, and is blackmailing him.
At the end of the book, Raleigh realizes that he blackmailed Pierce. (It doesn't take great perspicuity for Raleigh to realize this. He had run into Pierce and Lizzie sharing a hotel room in Charleston, and Pierce says "you'd be a fiend to try any more of your vile blackmail schemes.")
So what does Raleigh do? He immediately blackmails Pierce into giving his friend Mingo Sheffield, who lost his job at the beginning of the book, a new job—in fact, a job that Mingo is eminently qualified for.
But does Pierce actually understand people better at the end? There's not much evidence for this, and I would hazard that he only understands them marginally better.
1 Quite possibly true when the bad people are Knights of the Ku Klux Klan.
2 This episode vaguely resembles some of Don Quixote’s adventures, for example, the episode where he mistakes a band of travelers for a company of evil knights, and the episode where he attacks a group of innocent people, and is overcome by sheer numbers and brutally beaten up.
